# Is "in he came" grammatical?

Tags: prepositions, inversion

I understand that prepositional phrases can be placed before the subject, for example "In God we trust." I also understand that phrasal verb should not be separated, for example "up I give" does not make sense because "give up" is phrasal verb.

The question is, can I move an adverbial preposition (as opposed to a prepositional phrase), which usually follows the verb immediately but isn't a part of a phrasal verb, to before the subject and form sentences like "in he came", "up he climbed"?

Comment: You can, but it will give your sentence more of a "poetic" feel. If that's not what you want, you probably want to avoid this in most instances.

Comment: I'd say it's essentially the same "non-standard sequence" in *Up you get!, Off we go!* - so not always "poetic / literary". The first of those two is probably better classified as "motherese" (baby-talk).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You absolutely can! It adds a nice storytelling or dramatical aspect to your words. I would **recommend using this more in written language than spoken language**, (since it has a literary/poetic feel to it) though in an exciting anecdote or after-dinner story, this change in word order can really spice up a tale. 
You can also place a noun between the preposition and the verb.

> Up the tree he climbed.

Compare how mundane and ordinary conventional word order might sound in this anecdote:

> After running from the police and with his trousers falling down, **Bill climbed up the tree** with his pants in tatters and his pride in pieces.

We can jazz things up a bit by leading with the preposition:

> After running from the police and with his trousers falling down, **up the tree Bill climbed** with his pants in tatters and his pride in pieces!

TL;DR: This technique is best used in writing since it lends a poetic/literay feel to what you're saying. It is, however, entirely grammatically valid.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Part of my question was specifically about if the PP is one preposition alone. I guess I got the answer that it's valid, but is it still common or poetic as compared to PP with prepositions and nouns?

Comment: I think my answer covers more than one preposition. That is to say it doesn't really matter if there's more than one: Up and over they went | Down to the bottom they came.

Answer (score 3):

Although I agree with JMB's answer and JR's comment about this construction sounding somewhat poetic or literary when used in a narrative sense, I would like to add that the imperative forms in conjunction with the verb **go** are quite prevalent and natural in the spoken language when directing someone to proceed in any given direction. It is not at all uncommon to hear *in you go, up you go, down you go, out you go* usually a somewhat playful spoken nudge. With a sterner delivery, it can also be a firm dismissal.

Comment: Right you are. :-)